# AngularJs 1.5 ES6: bindings undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, es6-class, angular-components

bindings passed to component works in html, but undefined in controller.

```
<hero value="foo"></hero>
```

hero.component.js

```
import template from './hero.html';
import controller from './hero.controller';

let heroComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    value: '@'
  },
  template,
  controller
};
```

HeroController.js

```
class HeroController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'hero';
    console.log(this.value); // undefined!
  }
}
```

hero.html

```
<section class="hero">
  <h1>AngularJs ES6 Example</h1>
  <!-- Value is works within template -->
  <h3>You can find me inside {{ $ctrl.name }}.html {{ $ctrl.value }}</h3>
</section>
```

I am using angular version `1.5.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its is undefined because value was loaded after an api call, using  `ng-if` solved the problem

```
<hero ng-if="$ctrl.value" value="$ctrl.value"></hero>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that bindings are resolved during the constructor call. What angular internally does is instantiate the controller and inject dependencies on calling the constructor. Then, bindings are populated.

You should use the life-cycle hooks `$onInit` or `$onChanges` instead. Have a look at the developer guide [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) (the relevant section about life-cycle hooks is about half way down the page).

Comment: i tried in $onInit, but it is still undefined, my value will not change so i don't see a point to use $onChanges

Comment: @farhanlatheef 1.5.0 doesn't have $onInit, as I remember. Upgrade it to at least 1.5.3.

Comment: `$onInit` should be there in 1.5.0. However, you are correct `$onChanges` came with 1.5.3. Could you provide a plunkr outlining your problem? Is `foo` a defined property of the parent controller?